# Dealing with offset changes in an attempt to display date correctly

Tags: javascript, mysql, datetime, timezone-offset

I am working on a project and I need to display a timestamp. I am keeping the time inside the database in UTC format. Let's say the offset in my area is -4 hours (and assume I am in daylight savings time), so when I enter the time into the DB it enters 4 hours earlier. Now that it is winter, the offset is -3 hours. When I pull the information back out of the DB and change it back to standard time, only 3 hours get added to the time ––instead of 4. Therefore, all the items displayed one hour earlier than they should. So my question is- **There is a way to know the exact offset in a certain area that was at the moment the information entered to the DB?**

Comment: Yes, but it requires knowing the historical changes to the daylight offsets for the entire history of your dataset... Like the [IANA Time Zone Database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones). Or you could just store the offset in the database along with the UTC value.

Comment: If your offset is -4, then UTC is 4 hours **later**, not earlier. Creating a timestamp for a particular location is what the *timeZone* option in [*Intl.DateTimeFormat*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) is for. The rules to use are specified using an [IANA representative location](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), e.g. Pacific/Kwajalein.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're starting with a UTC date and time, you can use the [*Intl.DateTimeFormat* constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) with options to get the timezone offset for a particular [IANA representative location](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

E.g.

```js
function getOffset(s, location) {
  let getTz = lang =>
    new Intl.DateTimeFormat(lang,{
      timeZone: location, timeZoneName:'short'
    }).formatToParts(new Date(s)).reduce((acc, part) => {
      if (part.type == 'timeZoneName') {
        acc.tz = part.value;
      } return acc;
    }, Object.create(null)).tz;
    
  let offset = getTz('en');
  return (/\d/.test(offset)? offset : getTz('fr')).replace(/^[a-z]+/i, '');
}

let s = '2020-10-27T00:16:25.867Z';

console.log(`At ${s} the offset in these places is:`);
['America/New_York',
 'Europe/Paris',
 'Australia/Broken_Hill',
 'Pacific/Apia',
 'Pacific/Chatham'
].forEach(loc => console.log(`${loc}: ${getOffset(s, loc)}`));
```

Note that if the language used matches the default language for the host, then the short name of the timezone is returned. If it doesn't match, it's returned as UTC±H:mm or GMT±H:mm, where the minutes are only included if required. So the function first tries en, and if that doesn't work, uses fr. I haven't yet found where both en and fr return an abbreviation rather than an offset.